# How to Properly format Update syntax on OledbCommand?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2016

Update Syntax error.
NOTE:
Have updated the code and I get "object reference not set to an instance of an object", & the data does not get updated on the DB...
EDIT: Renamed the commands as suggested hopefully
any help is greatly appreciated...
[image]

```
 Command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Log SET Serial_Number = @Serial_Number , Material_Number = @Material_Number , Submitted = @Submitted , prt_Count1 = @prt_Count1 , prt_Count2 = @prt_Count2 , prt_Count3 = @prt_Count3 , Main_Relief = @Main_Relief , Crtg1 = @Crtg1 , Crtg2 = @Crtg2 , Crtg3 = @Crtg3 , Crtg4 = @Crtg4 , Crtg5 = @Crtg5 , Crtg6 = @Crtg6 , Crtg7 = @Crtg7 , Crtg8 = @Crtg8 , Crtg9 = @Crtg9 , Crtg10 = @Crtg10 , Crtg11 = @Crtg11 , Crtg12 = @Crtg12 , Rework = @Rework , aflrp_Repair = @aflrp_Repair , Operator_Initials = @Operator_Initials , Remarks = @Remarks , Pass_FailCrtg1 = @Pass_FailCrtg1 , Pass_FailCrtg2 = @Pass_FailCrtg2 , Pass_FailCrtg3 = @Pass_FailCrtg3 , Pass_FailCrtg4 = @Pass_FailCrtg4 , Pass_FailCrtg5 = @Pass_FailCrtg5 , Pass_FailCrtg6 = @Pass_FailCrtg6 , Pass_FailCrtg7 = @Pass_FailCrtg7 , Pass_FailCrtg8 = @Pass_FailCrtg8 , Pass_FailCrtg9 = @Pass_FailCrtg9 , Pass_FailCrtg10 = @Pass_FailCrtg10 , Pass_FailCrtg11 = @Pass_FailCrtg11 , Pass_FailCrtg12 = @Pass_FailCrtg12 " + "WHERE ID = @ID", con);


                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial_Number", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Material_Number", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Submitted", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = thisDay1;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prt_Count1", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prt_Count2", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prt_Count3", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Main_Relief", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox6.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crtg1", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox7.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crtg2", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crtg3", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox10.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crtg4", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox11.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crtg5", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox12.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crtg6", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox13.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crtg7", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox14.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crtg8", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox15.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crtg9", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox16.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crtg10", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox17.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crtg11", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox18.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crtg12", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(textBox19.Text);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rework", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox20.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aflrp_Repair", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox21.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operator_Initials", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox22.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox23.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_FailCrtg1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox24.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_FailCrtg2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox25.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_FailCrtg3", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox26.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_FailCrtg4", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox27.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_FailCrtg5", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox28.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_FailCrtg6", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox29.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_FailCrtg7", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox30.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_FailCrtg8", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox31.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_FailCrtg9", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox32.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_FailCrtg10", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox33.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_FailCrtg11", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox34.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass_FailCrtg12", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox35.Text;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = int.Parse(txtBoxID.Text);
```

Comment: Clearly this won't work: `WHERE[ID] =  txtBoxID.Text)`  That should be the last parameter (oledb parameters have to be in order they appear in the string.

Comment: *`textBox35.Text`* - yikes.. you know you're allowed to rename controls after you drop them on a form, right? Just think, if your entire program were full of things named like "type of thing plus number" then you'd be writing e.g. `UPDATE Table22 SET Column1 = @param1, Column2 = @param2, Column3 = @param3...` - nothing would make any sense

Answer (score 1):

Simple UPDATE queries typically look like:

```
UPDATE table 
SET column1 = @parameter1, column2 = @parameter2 ...
WHERE columnX = @parameterX ...
```

It looks like you've adapted an INSERT VALUES statement, which isn't the right syntax

OLEDB isn't fussy whether you use `?` or [`@xyz` for your parameter placeholders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWh6o.png), but you'll have to AddWithValue (or equivalent) as many placeholders as you have used, and in the same order. Unlike other providers you cannot reuse named parameters. This means for a statement like this:

```
UPDATE person
SET name = @n, age = @a
WHERE id = @i
```

Your C# will need something like:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("thename", nameTextbox.Text);      //will be used as the value for @n
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("theage", ageNumericUpDown.Value); //will be used as the value for @a
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("theid", idVariable);              //will be used as the value for @i
```

3 parameters added; I deliberately made the names different to highlight that they don't matter. The number and order of addition is critical. You cannot do this:

```
UPDATE person
SET birthname = @n, currentname = @n
WHERE id = @i

//not enough parameters AND the wrong order. You cannot re-use @n unlike on other DBs
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", ageNumericUpDown.Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", nameTextbox.Text);
```

<sub>*"Use `@xyz` if you want, but assume they're all just `?`s"*</sub>

---

Giving parameters a nice name is useful if you want to change the values and run the query again:

```
command.Parameters["theid"].Value = idVariable+1;
```

Comment: *"OLEDB isn't fussy whether you use `?` or `@xyz` for your parameter placeholders"*  The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#remarks) say otherwise.  *"The OLE DB.NET Framework Data Provider uses positional parameters that are marked with a question mark (?) instead of named parameters."*

Comment: True. In essence any `@parameters` are converted to ?, which is why you can't rely on them behaving like named parameters in other DBs, but parameters denoted by `@words` are allowed in the statements

Comment: @CaiusJard , hopefully I had updated the code as per your suggestion se OP... I can not get the data to save at all. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: You've put `AddWithValue("@ID", ...)` as the first parameter you add, but `"@ID"` appears last in the SQL. The left-to-right order of appearance of parameters in the SQL must match exactly the top-to-bottom order that parameters are `Add`ed to the `command.Parameters` parameter collection

Comment: @CaiusJard hello, have changed the arrangement as noted; however, the code is still giving me the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" appreciate any assistance

Comment: Which line are you getting that on?

Comment: It is not pointing to a line, it just pops up when I hit the update button

Comment: Stop the running app, in VS go to DEBUG menu>> WINDOWS>> EXCEPTION SETTINGS. put a check next to Common Language Runtime Exceptions. Now the code will pause as soon as the error occurs even if there is a try/catch for it. Edit the question to include a screenshot of the exception helper and the line of code VS is stopped on. If you can squeeze it in, the LOCALS window is handy too

Comment: @CaiusJard added the picture, let me know if this what you asked please. appreciate all you assistance thank you very much

Comment: AddWithValue doesn't work that way. AddWithValue takes the parameter name and the value. You've put the parameter name and a  member from the OleDbType enum (which will be taken as the value) and then tried setting the value again. Do like I put in the answer eg `AddWithValue("@something", textbox1.Text);`